# How do/Can I use LIKE in a MySQL view?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

If I create a view like so:

```
CREATE VIEW test_view AS SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somevalue LIKE 'test%';
```

...it looks like this when I come back to edit it (so obviously it doesn't work):

```
CREATE VIEW test_view AS SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somevalue LIKE '\0\0\0t\0\0\0e\0\0\0s\0\0\0t\0\0\0%';
```

What am I doing wrong? LIKE must be allowed in a view, so maybe the string should be escaped in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you’re seeing is obviously UTF-32, so your environment is apparently set up to use that encoding and not ASCII.  It is not necessarily a bad thing, but you need to set it up to display the character correctly (instead of the byte values); and also to make sure that the back-end really is using UTF-32 as well.

Other than that, it’s really hard to help if you don’t tell us how you edit and run your commands (where do you “come back” after you’ve typed the SQL command?).

Comment: Ah, thank you! That gives me a good clue to start googling again.

The client I'm using is MySQL Workbench with the 'Alter View' command after creating the view in the main query window (although the result is the same if I use the 'Add View' command instead of the query window). Not sure where it's getting UTF-32 from. The same thing happens if I create the view from the command line, so maybe it is my connection string that needs to change or something like 'SET NAMES' to be entered before creating the view.